# What does "crap" mean in samba logs?

Tags: samba

I have been googling and googling and can't find a conclusive answer. In log files for samba, I see things like the following:

> "[11560]: pam auth crap domain:" &
>   "NTLM CRAP authentication for user"

I'm hoping this stands for something like "Challenge Response Auth Protocol" or something, but when I show the logs to people that aren't technical, I usually get questions or looks.  Anything that anyone knows about this will greatly help.

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: If I remember correctly, it's something related to PAM when authenticating

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**C** hallenge **R** esponse **A** uthentication **P** rotocol.

See: http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Winbind#CRAP *("I think the pun is intended.")*

Comment: Wow, and I was just guessing.  I guess it makes sense, then.  Thank you.